# Popstate not working as expected(needs multiple clicks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history, popstate

I am trying to learn History Web API, but already have problems at the first hurdle.

I am able to get `history.pushState` working, but have issues with `popstate`. It works fine when clicked for the first time after `AJAX` page load, but if I load that same page again, I need to click back button twice. If I load it one more time, I need to click back three times, and so on.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
var $main = $('#main');


$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    loadPage(location.href); 
});

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState({}, '', href);
    loadPage(href);
    return false;
})

loadPage = function(href){
    $main.load(href);
}
})
```

Comment: It sounds like you may want `.replaceState()` instead...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works now without the need for multiple clicks. But I am still curious what is wrong with this code of mine, especially since I saw examples on the net using pushState and not having the need to click back button multiple times.

Comment: Guess I jumped the gun a bit. It doesn't do what I want. The back button functionality is now completely messed up.

Comment: How are you loading the same page multiple times? Just clicking the same link over and over?

Comment: @ryan0319 Yep, same link over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You need the state Object. In your case you using a empty Object wich will not work proberly. Just test is with a Object like this : {"url":yourUrlVar}

Reference: [History.pushState - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no luck. Same issue persists.